# Counting the passwords of length N using an alphabet containing M characters

Tags: combinations, permutation, dynamic-programming, combinatorics, counting

Say, there are **M** characters in our alphabet. We want to form the passwords (or character strings) of length **N**. Constraint is that all the passwords must contain every character from the input alphabet **at least once**. So, how many such passwords are possible?

Also, M <= N

**Example-1:** M = **4**, N = **4**, Answer = **24**

```
Answer = M! or N! (all permutations of length 4)
```

**Example-2:** M = **2**, N = **3**, Answer = **6**

```
Let M = {a, b}
Possible passwords are {aab, aba, baa, bba, bab, abb}
```

So, can we derive the **general formula** of counting such passwords for the given values of **M** and **N**?

Comment: I don't have time for a full answer, but have you considered a summation of your permutations/combinations?

Comment: @BrianJ, Yes I thought of this approach: Choose M places out of N, and then permutating it M! times and then repeating this process for the remaining (N-M) places, finally multiply all these numbers. But, it doesn't give correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I got the answer:

Answer = m! * S(n, m)

where, S(n, m) = [Stirling number of second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind)